# Distinct Strings when swapping is allowed

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There is an array of strings, I need to find distinct strings among them when swapping of characters are allowed. One character can only be swapped once.

For example-:

```
{"abcd","cdab"}
```

This will result in 1 as first string can be converted into second by swapping first with 3rd character and second with fourth character.

```
{"abcd","dbac"}
```

This will result in 2 as there is no possible swapping for conversion.

I tried with this approach

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-strings-odd-even-changes-allowed/

but it won't work when swapping is with odd and even.

Comment: So what is wrong with the approach that you found on this site? What is not working?

Comment: What happens with three or more strings?  What is the output in that case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen output would be if two strings are same it would be consider as one and rest of the strings will also count.
example: {"abcd","badc","adbc"} This will result in 2

Comment: @michalk This is only working when swapping is between even-even indexes or between odd-odd indexes

Comment: can you swap evan index char with odd index char?

Comment: @SSP yes you can

Comment: its true for your case or false {"abcd","dbac"}

Comment: You have not defined rules/limitations for swapping. If any chars might be swapped, then the second example should give 1

Comment: @SSP no 'a' is being swapped with 'd' but you can not swap 'a' again. So, it will be 2 in this case

Comment: @Mbo each character can only be swapped once

Comment: So edit your question and add this important information

Comment: By swapping chars at most once, you can do abcd = bacd, and bacd = bcad, but NOT abcd = bcad.  That doesn't really make sense as a way to define 'non-distinctness'.  Equivalence relations are transitive.  If you really want to use this rule then you have to be more explicit about what you are trying to find.  Number of disjoint subsets? Smallest partition into independent sets?  The GFG article you linked to has no such 'one swap' rule, so that problem is easy to solve and makes sense.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I got this problem in one of the interviews, i was puzzled too that's why i posted here if this problem has any solution.